# Re-enabling a button after few seconds

Tags: c#

What I want to do is that, I have a clear button that deletes every entered value. However, if I clicked it without entering values, it shows error. Therefore, I decided that if the user didn't enter any values, the Clear button will be disabled. However, when I do so, the Clear button wont become enabled again, so I want to put a timer that re-enables the Clear button after few sec's lets say 3 sec's. Can anyone help me please? btw it should be in C#
what i did so far

```
if (txtFirstActual.Text.Length > 0)
{
    //so that if the user clicked on Clear button without entering a value, it will disable the button
    button1.Enabled = true;               
}
else
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    // here, i want to put a timer here so that it re enables the button after few sec's
}
```

Comment: listen for value change events and change button state to enable/disable.

Comment: Why not show us the error and the code you use to delete these values.  It may be a much better solution to correct that code rather than patch it with a UI-hack.  You may want to re-use the deletion code in other places; this would make it better, more portable, and more re-usable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother with the runaround?  How about in button1's Click handler

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstActual.Text))
{
    // clear data
}
```

If a method call will fail in certain cases (ie: trying to clear if nothing is there) then the best approach is to perform the check where you are making the call.  This is usually much easier and cleaner than leaving dangerous code in the program and building locks and obstructions into the UI to try to prevent the user from accessing that dangerous code.

Answer (score 4):

Timer-based button checking is a bad-approach.  If you only want to enable the Clear button once data has been entered, you should subscribe to "[TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)" events in the Textboxes in which people enter the data.

For more information on subscribing to events, check out this MSDN article on "[Consuming Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ccyd347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)."

Answer (score 1):

How about enabling/disabling the button on text changed. Check the value. If it is Null or Empty disable otherwise enable button.

```
private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)sender).Text)))
      {
          MyClearButton.Enabled = false;
      }
      else
      {
          MyClearButton.Enabled = true;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
       MyClearButton.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: that seems awesome, but how can I do it

Comment: @MohammedTurki: What is it ASP/Winforms or WPF?

Comment: it's windowsform mate

Comment: should i edit it instead of String to int?since the user is supposed to enter a numeric value

Comment: @MohammedTurki: Please go ahead.

Comment: it still doesnt work :(
what i did is changing is to if(String.IsNullOrEmpty((txtFirstActual)sender).Text)
but it now says that txtFirstActual does not exit in the current context

Comment: it should be `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstActual.Text.ToString()))`